# Google checkout transaction number

Tags: php, google-checkout

I am working on a PHP website with Google checkout Payment. I need to get  the transaction id in the merchant calculation page using API Call back url. What method can I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Checkout offers a service similar to Paypal's IPN](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Notification_API) where they send all of the transaction information to a URL you specify. This includes the transaction number.